# C Commandline Arguments: Need Clarification About Order of Arguments Input And Commandline Arguments In General

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

This is a sample code from a book. This program prints a given string to repeat given number of times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void usage(char *program_name)
{
    printf("Usage: %s <nessage> <# of times to repeat>\n", program_name);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, count;

    if(argc < 3)
        usage(argv[0]);

    count = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("Repeating %d times..\n", count);

    for(i=0; i < count; i++)
       printf("%3d - %s\n", i, argv[1]);
}
```

It does what it should do:

```
kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/asm$ ./convert 'Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming' 6
Repeating 6 times..
  0 - Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming
  1 - Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming
  2 - Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming
  3 - Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming
  4 - Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming
  5 - Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming
kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/asm$
```

Q. Now although `main` takes two arguments in this specific order: `(int argc, char *argv[])`, why is that when I `./convert 'string' (number)` it works fine but other way around `./convert (number) 'string' does not work?

```
kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/asm$ ./convert 5 'Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming'
Repeating 0 times..
```

Q. This line
 `if(argc < 3) usage(argv[0]);`
I have 2 questions about: This line specifies that if the integer argument given is less than 3, the program should output the usage. `./convert 'string' 2` does not print the usage? So what is happening here? Also `usage` takes `char *program_name` as an argument(what is meant by `char *program_name`?) But in line above is given `argv[0]` as an argument. Why is this and what does this do?

Comment: When you do `./convert 'Stackoverflow is the best place to ask questions about programming' 6`, `argc` is not 6.

Comment: why the downvotes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argc` is the number of arguments on the command line, not the value of any particular argument. `argv` contains the actual arguments, which are passed as strings.  `argv[0]` is the command used to invoke the program, `argv[1]` is the first argument, etc.

When you call the program as

```
./convert 'Stackoverflow ...' 6
```

then

```
argv[0] == "./convert"
argv[1] == "Stackoverflow ..."
argv[2] == "6”
argc == 3
```

The code assumes that the number is passed in `argv[2]` and uses the `atoi` function to convert it from a string representation of an integer to an integer value, which is why the code didn’t behave as expected when you switched the order of the arguments.  If you want to be able to switch up the order of the arguments, then your code has to know how to detect which argument is which.

Comment: Ok. The book I am reading expected me to know this before reading the book.

Comment: @raincouver: Yeah, most C books and tutorials are ... not great.

Answer (score 1):

The `argc` variable is the number of elements in the `argv` array. And the actual command line arguments will be in the `argv` array.

The first argument on the command line will always be in `argv[1]`, the second in `argv[2]`, etc.

If you change the order when running the program, the program doesn't know about that, and will think that the string to print will still be in `argv[1]` and the number in `argv[2]`. If that's not true the program will fail to work properly.

The `argc` check only check the *number* of arguments, not their order.

---

The name of the program (`"./convert"`  in your question) is always passed as argument zero, i.e. in `argv[0]`.